# Set value in App.component.html from another component

Tags: angular, components

I'm a very beginner in angular, sorry for this question, but what are the ways I can change a value in the parent component (App component) from another generated component (BasicInfoComponent). i try this code but I think i misunderstand some ideas,
so please can you provide me with a very direct and short description.

```
    <div class="container">// app.component.html
    <img class="logo" src="./../assets/img/logo.png">
     {{sectionstatment}}
     <router-outlet [sectionstatment] = 'statment'></router-outlet>
      </div>


   export class AppComponent {// app.component.ts
     title = 'title';
   sectionstatment = '';
   }
     export class BasicInfoComponent implements OnInit {//basic-info.component.ts
       statment = 'hi' ;
       constructor() {
          }
```

Comment: Hey Jaber, there are many techniques for such component to component interaction and it may sound complicated at first but strongly suggest to learn all these from here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. In your case I would do a shared service and make both app.component and child component to import that service and "talk" to each other using it: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: thank you @SergeyRudenko , i followed this [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) at this section (Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service), but i have the following error in the console: 
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DataService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> DataService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DataService!

Comment: how did you import your provider? it has to be imported duly at app level first.

Comment: as the following in app.component
 import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

Comment: Bssically import the service (import { DataService } from "../data.service";) into your app.module.ts, ALSO add it (DataService) into providers section inside app.module.ts inside providers:[] array

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Solved, Thank you a lot, but what I misunderstood why the app component doesn't consider as a parent for all components since all components are injected into <router-outlet></router-outlet> directive.

Comment: So app.component is in fact parent to the other components, it does not mean though that a child component is "free" to talk to their parent but certainly there are ways. I think the moment you start building an app with quite a few components you quickly realize that this initial complexity is a good structure for bigger apps